# Pattern Recognition using OpenCV to detect and highlight bent pins

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new in OpenCV, image processing and also in Native language C/C++ for, and I would like to have some guides on where I should focus on in order to complete my task. I am developing an android application that can recognize the bent pins and circle/square the bent pins, for example the face recognition in openCV will "square" the human face once it was detected. The bent pins can be in defected in various different forms. I am using Eclipse ADT. Currently I had downloaded the Face recognition in OpenCV for android and I am analyzing it, and according to what I had discovered is that, it consist of an xml file, where it had been trained and is used for detection by the system. Now my questions are:

1. How can I train and generate the xml file?
2. What software should I use in order to train and generate the xml file?
3. What type of images do I need to retrieve in order to train the system/image requirements (eg, image of the bent pins from multiple angles)?
4. What is the best algorithm to achieve this?
5. According to my research I discovered that Face detection recognition is using Haar-like feature. What is the difference of Haar-like feature, cascade classifier and also artificial neural network? I am confused of the difference.  Are they the same thing?

Thank you

Comment: can you describe a more about your "bent Pins"? May be some image samples?

Comment: It look like the sample image given in this link http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w524/Aggie1295/CPUSocketPicture1_zps2eaf3a31.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1) 2) the pc-version of opencv comes with a tool named [opencv_traincascade](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html), this is used to generate the haar/hog/lbp xml-cascades off-line. (no, you don't run that kind of task on your smartphone)

3) 4) multiple(hundreds) images from your object, also even more negative (non-pin/background images)

5) haar [cascades](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) train on edge features like those:

[image]

so, here's the bummer: i seriously doubt, that your 'bent pins' come with enough 'edge features' for this.

Comment: thank you for the explanations, but may I also know what kind of software and tools is used to train it on pc? I am thinking maybe I can try training it on PC first and get the generated xml file to be used in the android application . And also besides the haar that uses edge feature, may I know if there are any other types that I can make research on that is suitable to detect the bent pins?